# Regex ending character can be one of 2

Tags: regex

I have a url that I am trying to get the id out of. Problem is, the url could look like this `"https://www.website.com/blah/1234567890:0"`, `"https://www.website.com/blah/1234567890/"` or `"https://www.website.com/blah/1234567890"`

It is now the first option that is giving me trouble. Basically, all I want is "1234567890", so for the last option, I need to omit the :0.

Here is what I tried when capturing id with/without ending /:

```
([^/]*)\/?$
```

Here is what I tried to cover both with/without ending / and the :0, but it does not work as I thought (id is match 6, but I've no way of knowing it will always be 6):

```
([^/]*)[/:?$]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note your `[/:?$]`  subpattern matches a single char, either `/`, or `:`, `?` or `$` (the `$` symbol inside `[...]` is not a special regex operator any longer).

You may make the first negated character class lazily quantified, and add an optional group that would match `/` or `:0` one or zero times:

```
([^\/]*?)(?:\/|:0)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9X7So/1). Replace `0` with `[0-9]` to match *any digit* at the end of the string.

**Details**:

- `([^\/]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `/` as few as possible (due to the `*?`  quantifier)
- `(?:\/|:0)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one of the two alternatives, 1 or 0 times: `/`  or `:0`
- `$` - end of string.